# Filter bad words | java 'replace'

Tags: java, filter, replace

In an attempt to filter the bad words, I found the 'replace' function in java is not as handy as intended. 
Please find below the code : 
Eg : consider the word 'abcde' and i want to filter it to 'a***e'.

```
    String test = "abcde";
    for (int i = 1; i < sdf.length() - 1; i++) {
        test= test.replace(test.charAt(i), '*');
    }
    System.out.print(test);
```

Output : `a***e`

But if the String is `String test = "bbcde";`, the output is `****e`. It seems, if the word has repetitive letters(as in here), the `replace` function replaces the repetitive letters
too. 
Why is it so? I want to filter the words excluding the first and last letter.

Comment: Do you want to filter bad words from another text, so that "abcde" is a bad word, which has to be filtered ? Or do you only want to get "a***e" from input "abcde" and "b***e" from "bbcde" ?

Comment: i want to get a***e from abcde! Got the answer. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because `String.replace(char, char)` replaces *all* occurrences of the first character (according to its [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29)).

What you want is probably more like this:

```
char[] word = test.toCharArray();
for (int i = 1; i < word.lengh - 1; i++) { // make sure to start at second char, and end at one-but-last char
    word[i] = '*';
}
System.out.println(String.copyValueOf(word));
```

Answer (score 0):

since `String.replace(char, char)` replaces all occurrences of specified char, this would be a better approach for your requirement:

```
String test = "abcde";
String replacement = "";
for (int i = 0; i < sdf.length(); i++) {
    replacement += "*";
}
test= test.replace(sdf, replacement );
System.out.print(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the replaceAll-Function:
[Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

With this you can replace all times you find a given substring in a string (f.e. "abcde") and replace all these with another string (f.e. "a***e").

```
String test = "abcde";
String replacement = "";
for (int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++) {
    if (i==0 || i==test.length()-1){
        replacement += test.charAt(i);
    } else {
        replacement += "*";
    }
}
sdf = sdf.replaceAll(test, replacement);
System.out.print(test);
```

Comment: This method takes a regular expression and it will replace every match to that regex. So it might behave different than you expect...

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question ? Didn't he want to find every appearence of the word "abcde" in a given text and replace them with "a***e" ? So for example in "blaabcdebla" he wants to receive "blaa***ebla" ?

Comment: @user2248673 Yes, but you probably want to actually still use replace instead of replaceAll. Otherwise your "a***e" will replace anything between any a and any e, and that is definitely not what we want. We know "abcde" is an evil word, but we don't also want to censor "alive" (or for that matter, "ale" and "agriculture", both of which would get caught by "a***e").

Answer (score 0):

> It seems, if the word has repetitive letters(as in here), the replace function replaces the repetitive letters too. Why is it so?

Why? Because that's just how it works, exactly as the API documentation of `String.replace(char oldChar, char newChar)` says:

> Returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of `oldChar` in this string with `newChar`.

If you just want to replace the content of the string by the first letter, some asterisks and the last letter, then you don't need to use `replace` at all.

```
String test = "abcde";

if (test.length() >= 1) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    result.append(test.charAt(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < test.length() - 2; ++i) {
        result.append('*');
    }
    result.append(test.charAt(test.length() - 1));
    test = result.toString();
}

System.out.println(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String test = "bbcde";
    String output = String.valueOf(test.charAt(0));
    for (int i = 1; i < test.length() - 1; i++) {
        output = output + "*";
    }
    output = output + String.valueOf(test.charAt(test.length() - 1));
    System.out.print(output);
}
```